# Download image from URL that automatically creates download

Tags: python, download

I have a url that when opened, all it does is initiate a download, and immediately closes the page. I need to capture this download (a png) with python and save it to my own directory. I have tried all the usual urlib and urlib2 methods and even tried with mechanize but it's not working.

The url automatically starting a download and then closing is definitely causing some problems.

UPDATE: Specifically it is using Nginx to serve up the file with a X-Accel-Mapping header.

Comment: first of all take a look at web developer tool s in your browser.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python

Comment: What about using wget? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872083/what-are-the-performance-related-issues-of-php-curl/17872132#17872132 or are you fixed on python?

Comment: @RodrigoGuedes It does the same thing all the others do, just kicks out a file with the name I give it but it's not a valid png. I can open it in sublime and it's actually html. Which is weird...

Comment: @Homer6 Nope it has to be python. It's being built into a pyramid webapp

Comment: How is the download triggered? Location header? Meta refresh? JavaScript?

Comment: Providing a sample URL that we can test against will get you much better results. First guess is that you'll need to enable redirect following in whatever library you are using. Second guess is you should use requests, a nicer python library for http, as they'll handle most cases gracefully.

Comment: @Imran it is a custom header I believe.

Comment: @LiyanChang I'm running it all locally so unfortunately I can't give a url

Comment: See the update in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing particularly special about `X-Accel-Mapping` header. Perhaps the page makes the HTTP request with ajax, and uses the `X-Accel-Mapping` reader value to trigger the download?

Here's how I'd do it with `urllib2`:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url_to_get_x_accel_mapping_header)
download_url = response.headers['X-Accel-Mapping']
download_contents = urllib2.urlopen(download_url).read()
```

Comment: The problem I was having ended up being something different from what I described in my question. But for anyone who comes upon this question later this should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
URL= YOUR_URL
IMAGE = URL.rsplit('/',1)[1]
urllib.urlretrieve(URL, IMAGE)
```

For details to dynamically download images from a url list [visit here](http://www.gadgetcluster.com/2014/07/download-images-from-urls-using-python/)